# use c++ template to generate JNI functions

Tags: java, c++, templates, binding, java-native-interface

I want to use C++ template to generate slot functions and register these functions to the jvm the java code can call, like:

```
template<typename Arg1>
void bind_native(const char* className, const char* staticMethodName, function<void(Arg1)>* slotFunc)
{
    JNINativeMethod sig;
    sig.name        = staticMethodName;
    sig.signature   = Wrapper<void(Arg1)>::Get().GetSignature();
    sig.fnPtr       = Wrapper<void(Arg1)>::Get().GetSlotFunc(slotFunc);

    // register to jni..
}

// bind our native function to java.
function<void(int)> cppIntFunc = [](int intFromJava) 
{ 
    printf("called from java");
};
bind_native("MyClass", "MyCppMethod", &cppIntFunc);

// we can also bind different functions with the same signature to jni.
function<void(int)> cppIntFunc1;
function<void(int)> cppIntFunc2;
bind_native("MyClass", "MyCppMethod1", &cppIntFunc1);
bind_native("MyClass", "MyCppMethod2", &cppIntFunc2);

// in java code:
class MyClas {
    private static native MyCppMethod(int i);
    private static native MyCppMethod1(int i);
    private static native MyCppMethod2(int i);
}
```

but question is, the same template generate the same function, so I can not distinguish which method is called in the jni therefore I can not get the original slot function back:

```
template<typename Arg1>
struct Wrapper
{
    void* GetSlotFunc(function<void(Arg1)>* slotFunc)
    {
        // how to map the slotFunc to the StaticJniFunc?

        return StaticJniFunc;
    }

    static JNICALL void StaticJniFunc(JNIEnv* e, jclass c, Arg1 param1)
    {
        // how to get the slotFunc back here? 

        (*slotFunc)(param1);
    }
};
```

maybe I need to find a way to get the running jmethodID from jni?

Comment: Instead of static methods, could you create Java objects, cram any data you need to keep in there, and call methods on that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a integer to the template as a parameter to make unique templates and use macro **LINE** to auto generate that integer (see note 1):

```
// note 1
template<int METHODID, typename Arg1>
struct Wrapper
{
    map<string, SlotFuncPtr> funMap;

    void* GetSlotFunc(const char* className, function<void(Arg1)>* slotFunc)
    {
        funcMap[className] = slotFunc; // note 2
        return StaticJniFunc;
    }

    static JNICALL void StaticJniFunc(JNIEnv* e, jclass c, Arg1 param1)
    {
        auto* slotFunc = funcMap[getClassName(c)]; // note2

        (*slotFunc)(param1);
    }
};

// note1
#define bind_native(name,f) bind_native_<__LINE__>(name,f)
```

Then bind_native(...) can generate different static method even for methods with same signature. and in case that same signature functions bound with the same line number, you can distinguish them from the jclass(see note2).

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is a bit late but I hope it will be useful to someone.
I had to bind C++ class (i.e. `C`) to Java class. I implemented Java class with `long peer` inside it to hold a pointer to native instance and method `C::fromJava` which calls `env->GetLongField(instance, peer)` and casts it to `C*`. This way I can do something like that:

```
#include <jni.h>

/* ... */
static JavaVM* vm;
static inline JNIEnv* getEnv() {
    JNIEnv *env;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    return env;
}

static thread_local JNIEnv* env = getEnv();

/* ... */

/*
 * It is simple. Those wrappers get native pointer from Java
 * object (from it's `jlong peer` field) and call given function `f`.
 * There are two almost identical templates. One for simple functions and one more for
 * class member functions.
 * In class member function wrapper pointer to object is available as `this`.
 * static_cast`ing let us use every single type, including `void`.
 * No need to use `__LINE__` or other integer to identify methods,
 * compiler does this automatically.
 * if `peer` field is 0 method is noop.
 */
template<class F, F f, auto defaultValue> struct wrapper_impl;
template<class R, class A0, class... A, R(*f)(A0*, A...), auto defaultValue>
struct wrapper_impl<R(*)(A0*, A...), f, defaultValue> {
    static R wrap(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, A... args) {
        A0* native = A0::fromJava(obj);
        if (native != nullptr)
            return f(native, args...);
        return static_cast<R>(defaultValue);
    }
};
template<class R, class C, class... A, R(C::*f)(A...), auto defaultValue>
struct wrapper_impl<R(C::*)(A...), f, defaultValue> {
    static R wrap(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, A... args) {
        C* native = C::fromJava(obj);
        if (native != nullptr)
            return (native->*f)(args...);
        return static_cast<R>(defaultValue);
    }
};
template<auto f, auto defaultValue = 0>
void* wrap = (void*)&wrapper_impl<decltype(f), f, defaultValue>::wrap;

/* ... */

struct Smth {
    static Smth* fromJava(jobject instance) {
        return (Smth*) env->GetLongField(instance, peer);
    }
    
    // `this` is got from jobject automatically
    void smth() {}
    static jfieldID peer;
};

// `instance` is got from jobject automatically
jboolean smthInvert(struct Smth* instance, jboolean someBool) {
    return !someBool;
}

/* ... */

jfieldID Smth::peer = nullptr;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* jvm, void* reserved) {
    vm = jvm;
    env = getEnv();
    
    Smth::peer = env->GetFieldID(env->FindClass("my.class"), "peer", "J");
    if (Smth::peer == nullptr)
        return -1;
    
    static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    #define m(name, signature, func) { (char*) #name, (char*) signature, (void*) func }
        m(smth, "()V", wrap<&Smth::smth>),
        m(invert, "(J)J", wrap<&smthInvert>),
        #undef m
    };

    return (0 == env->RegisterNatives(env->FindClass("my.class"), methods,
            sizeof(methods)/sizeof(JNINativeMethod))) ? JNI_VERSION_1_6 : -1;
}
```